# Flash link on static text

Tags: flash

in flash how to give a link on static text with the mouse over=underline effect....

please reply....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding hyperlinks to a static text is not straightforward as in the case of a normal text field because

- `StaticText` doesn't have `htmlText` property like a `TextField` - it inherits directly from `DisplayObject`.
- You cannot mimic it by listening to mouse events as `DisplayObject` doesn't dispatch mouse events - only an `InteractiveObejct` would dispatch mouse/keyboard events.
- There is no `graphics` property for a `DisplayObject`, hence you cannot mimic underlining behavior.
- The [authoring tool may export multiple text field objects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/StaticText.html#text) comprising the complete text. For example, for vertical text, the authoring tool will create one text field per character.

May be you can work around these limitations by wrapping the static text inside a `Sprite` - but I would use a `TextField` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'm checking into this now, +1 but I hope this is not right :)

Comment: Be sure to check out http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1957523 for how to add links to text.

Comment: @yar does it say anything about adding hyperlinks on StaticText?

Comment: @Amargosh, no: however, why do you care whether it's static or dynamic text? The only advantage is the formatting. So while it's amazingly roundabout, you take your static text, convert it to HTML, and plug it in using ActionScript and then you can have links in it. I do not think the question really required it to be StaticText (though it says that).